# Laravel eloquent оптимизация

Tags: php, laravel

Недавно понадобилось извлечь из таблицы 1600 товаров + из отдельной таблицы артикулы + бренды из тоже отдельной таблицы. Казалось бы сделал что нибудь вроде `Products::with('sku')->get();` и вроде бы вся проблема.

Но laravel конвертирует все в объекты... А это очень серьезно замедляет. Замедляет настолько, что выдача 1600 товаров занимает 22 секунды...

Я просто хочу получить массив данных, не создавая объекты. Как мне этого избежать?

И сразу еще 1 вопрос, если я хочу получить, к примеру, айдишники продуктов сразу в виде массива, тоже не создавая объекты, как это сделать?

Просто привидите пример, я уже 4 часа тыкаюсь по документациям, далеко не продвинулся

Comment: Используйте тогда прямой запрос, как там `DB::select('your query')` или получите соединение с БД и работайте через него вообще.

Comment: А вы видели хоть один сайт, где на пользователя вываливаются 1600 объектов? А у некоторых мобильный интернет

Comment: @ArchDemon у меня пагинация по 10 стоит, просто он 1600 объектов получает

Comment: Ну так выбирайте по 10 объектов. А не 1600 а потом из них 10. Если бы у вас было 100000000 объектов, вы бы их тащили в php из БД, а потом обрезали до 10? Думаю, нет. Вы бы выбрали сразу 10

Comment: @ArchDemon то есть пользоваться стандартной опцией paginate(10) не нужно что ли?

Comment: Вы как-то непонятно объясняете. То у вас выдача по 10, то по 1600. Где правда?

Comment: @u_mulder я не доконца разобрался. чтобы 100% правильно объяснять)))

Comment: Ну если вас устраивает 22 секунды на выдачу, то можете выбирать 1600, а потом урезать до 10. В остальных случаях я советую пользоваться SQLым `LIMIT` (не знаю как это будет выглядеть через laravel)

Comment: Ну так вот чтобы было ясно и понятно где затык - надо вставлять реальный проблемный код, а не описывать гипотетические выборки.

Comment: Pagination сделает всё для вас - и смещение просчитает, и ограничение использует (https://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination).

Answer (score 0):

```
Products::with('sku')->first();
```

ето вернет тебе не object;
можеш делать так

```
$product = Products::with('sku')->first();
$product->phone //столбец  product из sql
```

Comment: Products::with('sku')->first(); я так получу 1 объект

Answer (score 0):

Если на страницу попадает в итоге только 10 записей то используй skip() и take() для выборки из базы только этих значений и их выводи, только,  скорее всего тебе надо будет перенастроить твою таблицу на серверный рендеринг. Второй вопрос, чтобы получить только массив каких то значений надо в конце запроса писать ->pluck()  и будет массив значений.